Coat isn't properly attaching to rigged character -- only one half is correctly attaching
I tried attaching the coat to the rigged Mixamo character the following way:

Select coat. shift + select armature. Ctrl + P > ‘empty groups’.

Select character mesh. shift + select coat. Weight paint mode > weights tab at top > transfer weights. >

In ‘source layers selection’ in bottom left 'transfer weights' panel, change from 'active layers' to ‘by name’.


I successfully attached all other items of clothing in this way, so I don't really know why the coat is glitching like this... it's like one half has correctly attached and the other hasn't.
Does anyone have any clues as to what the hiccup is?
Rest position:

Pose position:

